# How to show only child categories using the_category();

Tags: categories

I'm using **the_category();** on my category.php template to show the category's name — the problem is that it attaches the category's parent category. Is there any way to show only child categories using **the_category();**?

Comment: Please post an example of the code you're employing so that we can get a better idea as to what you're trying to accomplish/where you may be going awry.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
    if ($category->category_parent  == '7') {
        echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf(__( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> ';
    }
}
?>
```

All you need to do is replace 7 with whatever category you want to include